# How to change text color inside the radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I making a test and if answer is right i wanna change text color of checked radiobutton to green, else to red. Can I do this with code i have or should i change all structure.

HTML:

```
<div class="test-section">   
    <h3>Quastion #1</h3>
     
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="false" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span> 
    </div>
  
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="true" id="value2" type="radio" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="false" id="value3" type="radio" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var result = 0;
function check()

{
   var question;
   var choice;

   for (question = 1; question <= 10; question++) {
      var rigth_anwswer;
      var q = document.forms['quiz'].elements['q'+question];
      debugger;
      for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
         if (q[i].checked) {
            choice = q[i].value;
            if (choice == "true") {
               result++;
               //get span that contains text and change text color
            }
         }
      }
   }
   alert(result);
}
```

Comment: `debugger;`? Where is the actual attempt to change colors? There isn't any way that the code even works as suggested. Where's `<form>`? Please see [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: There is enough information provided to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the text color, just use some simple HTML DOM styling:

```
if (choice == "true") {
  result++;
  q[i].style.color = (whatever color you need it to be);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with css:-

```
<div class="test-section">   
    <h3>Quastion #1</h3>
     
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="false" id="value1" type="radio" checked="checked" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span> 
    </div>
  
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="true" id="value2" type="radio" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span>
    </div>
  
    <div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="false" id="value3" type="radio" />
        <span class ="answer-text">
            Value 
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[name="q1"]:checked + span{
  color: red;
}
```

Working example:- https://codepen.io/rejownahmed/pen/GRddPXP

Comment: They only want to change the color if the user gets the question right

Comment: Use clickevent then. Attach onClick with every input element. Then grab that input in the event by calling, e.currentTarget. then check if it is checked. (Like:- e.currentTarget.checked) if true then get the value like, e.currentTarget.value. then compare with the right one. If true made it’s color green and others red.